# Drools - Unable to cast object in rules THEN clause - used to work in older version

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I'm running on Optaplanner 8.0.0.Final, the corresponding drools version I believe is 7.46.0.Final. This rule used to work fine on Optaplanner 7 (7.45.0.Final, drools version is also 7.45.0.Final).

my rule looks like this:

```
rule "a_rule"
when
    $shiftList: List() from accumulate($shiftSlot: ShiftSlot(true))
then
    for(int i = 0; i < $shiftList.size(); i++) {
        ShiftSlot shiftObject = (ShiftSlot) $shiftList.get(i);
    }
    doSomething();
end
```

It will throw

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: Node argument doesn't contain typed expression!
```

If I remove the line
`ShiftSlot shiftObject = (ShiftSlot) $shiftList.get(i);` or replace it with

`Object shiftObject = $shiftList.get(i);` it runs fine, but it will be useless because I need to call methods from it later.

Anybody know what's wrong? The complete error stack trace shown below.

Comment: Any number of things can be wrong. Please upgrade to a recent version of OptaPlanner and report back.

Comment: Does it work if you move the cast to a separate statement? Eg. assign `.get(i)` to an Object, and then on a seperate statement cast it to a ShiftSlot ? There was a (much) older version of Drools with a similar bug that could be worked around like this.

Comment: That being said, in the example described, you don't even need a for-loop. You could just get the `$shiftSlot` on the left hand side, skip the accumulate, and `doSomething()` on the right. You don't seem to use the List for anything other than iteration, and Drools will automagically iterate for you if you let it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, this seems to be a bug with drools,  I upgraded to optaplanner 8.22.0 and it works fine now.